# How to separate values received from a serial port and store it as separate variables in python?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am new to python, to sensors and Stackoverflow. I am working on a project at my uni to read 4 sensor data on COM4 of my pc through pyserial. I wrote the below code to accomplish this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=5)
ser.write("\r".encode())
response =  ser.read(60)
print (response)
ser.close()
```

I get the output something like:

```
b'reply:node01\r\n69\r\n45\r\n117\r\n994\r\n
```

Values 69,45,117,994 are readings from the 4 sensors respectively. I did some research and changed `print (response)` to `print (response.decode('utf-8'))` , now I get the output which looks like:

```
reply:node01
69
45
117
994
```

I really need some help in separating and storing the sensor values from my initial output or from the output that I received after adding `print (response.decode('utf-8'))` as separate variables, something like field1=69, field2=45, field3=117, field4=994. So that I can send this to thingspeak API:

```
https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&field1=69&field=45&field3=117&field4=994
```

PS: Scalable - more number of sensors might be added at later stage of this project, so the number of data values received will also increase.

Please, I really need some help with this.

Comment: investigate [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), to split your response on the carriage returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good call on the conversion to text from bytes. Now suppose you store that decoded string, as in

```
my_str = response.decode('utf-8')
```

You can use the `splitlines` string method to get strings for each line:

```
field0, field1, field2, field3, field4 = my_str.splitlines()
```

Then you can interpolate those values into some template to give you the URL you want. If you'd prefer a list of the values, just use

```
fields = my_str.splitlines()
```

Comment: `splitlines` string method works. I am able to save each data individually now. Thanks a ton !